# Can't get association working in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm having difficulties getting an association to work with [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

I have the following models.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Retailer
end
```

and

```
class Retailer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :Products
end
```

My form partial (products/_form.html.erb) contains the following

```
<%= simple_form_for(@product) do |f| %>
...
<% f.input :currency %>
<% f.association :retailer %>
...
```

It works without the association, but with it I get the following error:

```
undefined method `retailer_id' for #<Product:0x007ffbe0f7d530>
```

I'm (obviously) quite new to this, but haven't been able to work this out.

edit: checked I'd run migrations and they are up-to-date.  The Retailer table has an id column!

```
> Retailer.all
Retailer Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "retailers".* FROM "retailers" 
=> [#<Retailer id: 1, name: "Retailer 1" etc...
```

chema file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120308195055) do

  create_table "alerts", :force => true do |t|
   t.string   "url",        :null => false
   t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
   t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "products", :force => true do |t|
      t.string   "title",                      :null => false
      t.integer  "price_cents", :default => 0, :null => false
      t.string   "currency",                   :null => false
      t.string   "asin",                       :null => false
      t.datetime "created_at",                 :null => false
      t.datetime "updated_at",                 :null => false
  end

    create_table "retailers", :force => true do |t|
      t.string   "name",       :null => false
      t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
      t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `belongs_to :Retailer` and `<% f.association :retailer %>` in your model and form for Product respectively, you'll need to add a `retailer_id` column to your products table.

You are missing `t.references :retailer` in your migration file for creating products table.
That is why, I quote you "it works without the association, but with it the error is `undefined method 'retailer_id' for #<Product:0x007ffbe0f7d530>`"

Yes, the retailers table has an `id` column but in order to reference a retailer from a product, your products table requires a `retailer_id` column.